# How to get the top 4 integers from a file.

Tags: java, arraylist, stringtokenizer

I have a file where the is a list of names, gender and a count of how many people have that name.

Example:

Garret,M,416

Sarah,F,800

Bernard,M,413

Jessica,F,1300

Barry,M,408

Derick,M,407

Mitchel,M,407

Nathanael,M,404

I am trying to get the top 4 names that have the highest count of names, but I am having trouble doing so. I have tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I am getting can't find symbol errors. Also i wanted to know if there was a more efficient way of doing this function because if I have to find the top 10 of an even bigger file, the way that I'm doing it could get really long.

```
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();



        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());


        OneName list = new OneName(name, sex, count);

        oneName.add(list);      


    }

    String many= oneName.get(0).toString();
    int a = oneName.get(0).getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i< oneName.size(); i++)
    {

        int b = oneName.get(i).getCount();
        int c = oneName.get(i).getCount();
        int d = oneName.get(i).getCount();
        String man= oneName.get(i).toString();
        if ( a < b)
        {
            a = b;
            b = a ;

        }
        if (b < c)
        {
            b = c; 
            c = b; 
        }
        if (c < d)
        {
            c = d;
            d = c;

        }

    }

    System.out.println(a+b+c+d);
    }
```

Comment: please supply us with the error trace. for "making it easier" i would suggest you using the collections sort with a comparator lambda.

Comment: *can't find symbol errors* meas that you are using variable name which you have not already defined or are defined later in the code than the first usage.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the type of `oneName`. If it's a list, you can use the `Collections.sort()` method from standard API:

```
Collections.sort(oneName, new Comparator<OneName>()
    {
        public int compare(OneName o1, OneName o2)
        {
            return o2.getCount() - o1.getCount();
        }
    });
```

Then the first 4 elements of `oneName` will be the ones with the highest count.

In your code, just replace your last loop by the above call to `Collections.sort()`. You can then get the 4 highest counts (you'll have to check for array index in bounds):

```
OneName a = oneName.get(0);
OneName b = oneName.get(1);
OneName c = oneName.get(2);
OneName d = oneName.get(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement the comparable interface in oneName

public int compareTo(Object o)
    {
         int ont =   this.get(i).getCount();
        OneName oneName = (OneName)  o;
        int ont1 =   oneName.get(i).getCount();
        return ont>ont1;
    }

Collections.sort(onename);
check the count in compare method and it will sort in desc order.
then take the first element from list.